# Connecting to Elasticsearch 6.2.3 with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Trying to figure out how to get a working config for spring boot to connect to Elasticsearch 6.2.3, here's my connection code:

**pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my connection code:

```
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig {

@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() throws 
UnknownHostException {

    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.sniff", true).build();

    // Can't resolve symbol "PreBuiltTransportClient" 
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);

}
```

}

Comment: Hey Michael. I have got the same configuration and its works fine. Also I can see `Transport address` is an `interface` in `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: Can you pass me the connection code you use?

Comment: Or if you can point me to the docs where you found it, that would even be more helpful. It's hard to reconcile the ES API vs. the Spring Data API without some code samples relevant to the versions I'm working with.

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use 6.x. Anyway you can check supported versions here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RC3/reference/html/#preface.versions

Comment: This answer is no longer up to date. Now it is supported.

Comment: Link does not exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

I am able to connect to the last current Elasticsearch server (`6.4.2`) using `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` version `2.1.0.RC1`. Please check the next configuration, I think it should work for `6.2.3`.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>dino-pocs</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch-spring-boot-integration</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Elasticsearch Integration with Spring Boot</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.6.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Wait for the next release version... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <!-- When next release version of spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 
        artifact appears you won't need this repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

**Configuration class** (remember to set `basePackage` value if you need to and host, port, and cluster name in `application.properties` or `application.yml`)

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.config.EnableElasticsearchRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "<your-base-packages>")
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String esHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int esPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String esClusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {
        Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", esClusterName).build();
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
        client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch v6 plus is supported now. Make sure to check the correct versions of spring-data-elasticsearch on your POM.xml

Here are the version support matrix from Spring-data:

[spring-data-elasticsearch supported version mapping](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch#quick-start)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `David`'s answer here is the list of supported ES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a dependency version conflict. Instead of adding Elasticsearch dependencies manually use the spring boot starter for elasticsearch.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have a code sample for the connection API I would use for this set of jars? There have been a few shifts in the connection API for ES, I was struggling getting it to connect which is how I landed on the above versions. Now I'm using the starter, but a few of the classes aren't available (like PreBuiltTransportClient) and TransportAddress is abstract in this version as well.

Comment: I've upgraded to : 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

No joy :(

Comment: What is the Spring Boot version you are using?

Comment: <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

Comment: TransportClient and TransportAddress are both elasticsearch objects though

Answer (score 0):

If all fails you can still rely on an old-fashion connection using REST call to ES. Sometimes it's better to use it when you are writing very complicated search operations. Since all, you have to fo form the JSON and call the exact API.

Note: The only drawback is you will create a direct connection to ES node and if that node goes down the operations will fail. 
To overcome it you can use a load balancer and instead call the load balanced API.